# React router only works for the first path listed, not for all

Tags: reactjs, react-router, conditional-statements

If I swap them, then it again works only with the first path.
How to write the code correctly?
loginForm and second page are components

```
{user === null ? loginForm()
      : (
     <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/">
          SecondPage(user.name,handleLogout)
        </Route>
        <Route path="/users">
          <span>users</span>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
     </div>
)}
```

Comment: `/` will match all the routes and `Switch` component only renders the first matching `Route` component.

Comment: Use exact path for /

Answer (score 0):

You have to use exact in the Route here, more details here

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route

exact: bool
When true, will only match if the path matches the location.pathname exactly.

```
<Route exact path="/one">
  <About />
</Route>

path    location.pathname   exact   matches?
/one    /one/two    true    no
/one    /one/two    false   yes
```

Answer (score 0):

informative scrupulous answer was to me, while I solved it by removing switch tag